# Determine the current orientation

Tags: windows-phone-7, mobile, windows-phone-7.1

I would like to determine the current orientation of the device in a WP7 app. I do not want to handle the OrientationChange event, because I need the current orientation when the page is opened.

I've been trying to do it with this piece of code I found in a forum:

```
((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Orientation
```

However, this always returns with PortraitUp, even if I turn the device sideways. And by the way, I am trying to do this with the emulator, so it might be an emulator-bug.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the keyboard in the emulator? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402568(v=vs.92).aspx

Comment: No, I found that already after one hour of headbanging because the OrientationChanged event did not even fire. That works now, and the event arguments give back the correct orientation. However, I want to know the orientation in the PageLoad.

Comment: Mark, you can call Orientation property only after first LayoutUpdated event. In page Loaded event it will be always PortraitUp, because OrientationChanged event raised after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I found out about this:
`((PhoneApplicationFrame)Application.Current.RootVisual).Orientation` does not have the correct orientation in PageLoaded.

It does not give back the correct orientation in the first LayoutUpdated event either. However there is a second LayoutUpdated event, in which it gives the correct one.
And between the two LayoutUpdated events, if the last page was in another orientation, then there will be an OrientationChanged event as well.

So there was no other solution for me then waiting for the OrientationChanged event to happen (because the only page the user can come to this page from supports only Portrait mode).

Answer (score 4):

Just tested it on the emulator and on my device. In the emulator it's like Mark is metioning it's always returning PotraitUp.

However if i test it on my device than the correct orientation is directly returned. So probably as Mark is suggesting it's a emulator bug.

Comment: Good to hear, I am going to test in a device tomorrow and tell if had any success. Thanks

Comment: Strange, but my device has the same behavior as emulator. Just write the test app that shows orientation in different events (launched in landscape mode):
LayoutUpdated: PortraitUp,
Loaded: PortraitUp,
LayoutUpdated: LandscapeLeft,
OrientationChanged: LandscapeLeft,
LayoutUpdated: LandscapeLeft

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.. and it worked perfectly.. hope this helps others..

```
PageOrientation orient = Orientation;
CheckOrientation(orient);
```

The above code gets the orientation of the current page. Call it in method of your class. Then, you can perform the following

```
private void CheckOrientation(PageOrientation orient)
    {
        if (orient == PageOrientation.LandscapeLeft || orient == PageOrientation.LandscapeRight)
        {
            //Do your thing
        }
        else if (orient == PageOrientation.PortraitUp || orient == PageOrientation.PortraitDown)
        {
            //Do your thing
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good to see `Orientation` property. Helped me a lot to manually call `OrientationChanged` event.

Answer (score 0):

Your application must support Landscape orientation to receive it. If you support only Portrait, than you never get nor OrientationChanged event and Landscape orientation in provided property.

Comment: SupportedOrientations="PortraitOrLandscape" is set in my page, if that's what you meant.

Answer (score 0):

**The solution is:**

```
public YourPhonePage()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PageOrientation currentOrientation = (App.Current.RootVisual as PhoneApplicationFrame).Orientation;

  if (currentOrientation == PageOrientation.PortraitUp)
  {
    // Do something...
  }
}
```